# Chrome ignoring the extension suggested in the Content-Disposition header of an HttpResponse sent from a WebAPI controller

Tags: c#, google-chrome, http, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to write a WebAPI controller that generates a Windows shortcut file (.lnk) on the fly and sends it back to the client, but even when I'm specifying ".lnk" as the extension in the Content-Disposition header when building the response, Chrome still changes it to ".download" in the Save As dialog. I've tried with both application/x-ms-shortcut and application/octet-stream as the Content-Type, but it has the same behavior in both cases.

Does anyone know how to avoid this and force it to suggest "Link.lnk" in the dialog?

*Note 1: I'm using Chrome 47*.

*Note 2: It works fine in IE 11*.

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
var stream = new FileStream(linkPath, FileMode.Open);
response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);

response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "link.lnk" } ;
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-ms-shortcut");
response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;

return response;
```

Comment: A comment [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1503#c25) seems to suggest that in some cases, if the download can be used maliciously (I can think of several ways to wreak havoc with a `.lnk` file), then it is re-suffixed with `.download`. [A further post](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1503#c79) in the thread indicates a user who has also experienced your exact problem. I think the answer here is "because security".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thorough version of my comment above...

If you look at the chromium source code in a method called [`EnsureSafeExtension`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/net/base/filename_util_internal.cc&l=184&cl=GROK), we see the code:

```
if (IsShellIntegratedExtension(extension))
  extension = kDefaultExtension; //<--"download"
```

where `IsShellIntegratedExtension` returns true for `lnk` extensions:

```
if ((extension_lower == FILE_PATH_LITERAL("local")) ||
    (extension_lower == FILE_PATH_LITERAL("lnk")))
  return true;
```

the comment in the code says:

```
// Right-clicking on shortcuts can be magical.
```

So, you're seeing intended behaviour, due to vulnerabilities perceived by the Chrome developers to lurk in the right-click behaviour of `.lnk` files.