# .lnk File downloading as .download in Chrome and it failed to download in first attempt in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working on system in which i am creating dynamic shortcut file of .lnk extension.

code as below

```
<form class="form-horizontal"><div class="form-body">                 
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Date</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <input class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium date_picker" size="16" type="text" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
        <a href="http://192.10.21.20/nikhil_v2/theme/templates/pages/Downloads/Daily Report/2019/03/12/nikhil_report_-_12_Mar_2019.lnk" target="_blank" id="submit" class="btn purple"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> DOWNLOAD</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

In chrome browser after click on download button, file will get downloaded in browser but at the time of saving file it changes its extension from .lnk to .download automatically.

While running same page in Firefox browser the file starts to download and failed to download. after retrying to download this file will get downloaded successfully and it can open the correct file.

if same code is executed in explorer browser then error will not occur and file downloaded successfully and can be accessible.

I want to download same lnk file in all of the browser.

Kindly help me in this.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same issue. It looks like the .LNK extension is deemed unsafe by the Chrome developers so its extension is replaced with .download.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34890432/2491027

Looks to have always been the case as well, from this comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1503#c25