# How to download .lnk file in html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I've a shared directory reachable by html page in this way

```
<div onclick="windows.open('file://mypath/mysharefolder','_blank');">Shared folder</div>
```

This works with internet explorer, but not with Chrome browser (error: Not allowed to load local resource).
So I've thought of replacing the link with a tag to allow the download of a lnk file (created manually) containing the path of the shared directory like this

```
<a href="mylinktofolder.lnk" download>Shared folder</a>
```

this tag works to download other kind of file (img,pdf,...), but not with lnk file; download in Chrome fails because doesn't find file *mylinktofolder.download*.

Is it possible to download such a file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Chrome marks .lnk files as unsafe for download so you won't be able to workaround this using html/js unfortunately

Sources:

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55177641/lnk-file-downloading-as-download-in-chrome-and-it-failed-to-download-in-first\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55177641/lnk-file-downloading-as-download-in-chrome-and-it-failed-to-download-in-first%5C)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34890432/2491027

Comment: So there is no way to make links to shared directories work with chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to download such a file?

Yes, sort off, here I show two tabs but the second is as you described a shared folder that was opened as second tab, however, has been torn off to show the two types of links in the first index.html

[image]

**So to answer your question** the second link tested with a range of LNK files lastly to a cmd.exe.lnk and onclick triggers a lnk download but as normal for windows the .lnk extension is not shown as actioned, so if the lnk is

- a file like svg.lnk it will open the linked svg in the second tab.
- **a lnk to a folder it will open the folder**
- a lnk to a command it in turn forces cmd.exe to be downloaded with a warning

[image]

and you can accept (keep) and run that copy of cmd !

[image]

All the above is possible **using Chrome based browsers such as Edge or SlimJet or Ungoogled Chrome**. and Chrome too.

```
<div onclick="window.open('file://c:/mysharedfolder','_blank');">Shared folder</div>
<div onclick="window.open('file://C:/myshortcuts/downloads.lnk','_blank');">downloads.lnk</div>
```

[image].

As non admin user I can navigate to local shares or remoteshares or remote mapped drives without any authorisation, other than I have user read write permission for all those locations.
[image]
[image: C:\TEMP\HTA]

```
<div onclick="window.open('file://C:/TEMP/HTA/share(local).lnk','_blank');">Local Shared folder</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but with windows.open on shared directories, Chrome returns always "Not allowed to load local resource".