# Lnk files are saved as .download files

Tags: firefox, directory, download, lnk

I have an online application, which allows me to save and edit different projects in Firefox. Each project has a directory on a shared drive. The application included a button to open the project directory for a chosen project. After an Firefox update however, the link to the folder is saved as a "#.lnk.download" file. I have discovered that removing the .download at the end allows me to open the directory as usual.
So ultimately, my goal is to get back the form of "#.lnk" However, I am still not sure on how to automatically remove the .download, so that others are able to open the directories like they normally would. What changed after the update?

I can only think of manually downloading the now files and remove the ".download" at the end manually.
Other browsers don't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature because .lnk files are commonly used as a [attack vector](https://intezer.com/blog/malware-analysis/how-threat-actors-abuse-lnk-files/) to deliver malware. This is implemented by all or at least most common browsers.

Currently there is no known way around it.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888806/chrome-ignoring-the-extension-suggested-in-the-content-disposition-header-of-an/34890432#34890432) thread for more details.